# How can i remove space between layout and background?

Tags: android, android-layout

What i have is a relative layout which contain other two relative layout and each of them have images and i have made each image as background to it's relative layout but still i can see a space between the image (the layout) and the whole parent layout .. So how can i remove this space??
This is my XML code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/upper" >
    </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
                android:background="@drawable/down" >

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="280dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>    
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Seriously? This doubt you had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding in your top level layout

Answer (score 0):

Remove all padding properties from main `RelativeLayout`.

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/upper" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
                android:background="@drawable/down" >

        <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="280dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


       </ListView>    
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This may help you..

Answer (score 0):

Your Relative Layout defined as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

Here you have defined that it should always have margin on all sides with these attributes:

```
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Simply remove them and you should be fine.

What you want:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```